# git log --follow to show on XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, xcode4

I just moved files on my xcode project and trying to preserve the commit history. And it works via `git --follow` but not when just doing git log and XCode doesn't capture this. What is the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use git from the command line.

Comment: when I push to github, I also don't see the history

Comment: You mean you don't see history through github as you do through git log --follow, correct? History is identical no matter what. If you are using `git log --follow`, then so beit. Github gives you some options you can add to the url to show different things. I know w=1 is something that will ignore whitespace on diffs. Not sure if there is an equivelant for --follow.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk.. yea I am looking for the --follow in the URL

Comment: why not just use `git log --all` on the command line with -p, --stat, --graph and other modifiers? less will allow you to search in the output with "/s/sometext"

Comment: I am just annoyed that when I move a file.. it detects it as I've renamed the file and it doesn't preserve all of the history when I do git log.. I'd have to use --follow. In this case, it's hard when I want to do diffs

Comment: It preserves all history as snapshots. Even if you change the file and move it, commands like git log will let you follow that. In fact you can give it a different threshold for what constitutes a move (how much of the file changed in the process). It would be really bad if it made an arbitrary decision to track moves and bake into the history a threshold that's no longer changeable. So moves and copies are a discoverable. Does this make sense?

Comment: This answer is not really helpful. We know that git from the command line is more powerful. However, it would be better to have Xcode to default using 'git --follow', so we can visually see the differences between several versions of renamed files in Xcode's UI. At least Xcode´s blame mode works fine even with renamed files.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this problem too.  It seems fixed as of Xcode 5.1 Beta 3.